# How to remove appended element usng jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating a form. On submit of form for each input field there is an errorbox that is appended when that input field is not filled. I want to remove or display off that errorbox onFocus of that input field.While in my code that will remain at that position. I tried and I went through all of similar posts but not able to find solution. Thank you!

**html code is like**

```
<div class="rowform">
        <label for="name">Name<span>*</span>:</label>
        <input type="text" class="mid" name="name" id="name" onFocus="fcs();"/><span id="name_error"></span>

    </div>
```

**script**
//on submit of form how I am appending errorbox

```
if($("#listcontact #name").val()==""){
    $("#name_error").append("<div class='formerror'>Please enter your name</div>");
}
```

//the on Focus function is like

```
    function fcs()
{
$(".formerror").remove();}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like:

```
$(".rowform").on("focus", "input", function(){
    $(this).closest(".rowform").find(".formerror").hide();
});
```

**Update:** Indeed no need of event delegation like Ian said.

```
$(".rowform").find('[type="text"]').on("focus", function(){
    $(this).closest(".rowform").find(".formerror").hide();
});
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ar7AT/

Comment: No reason for event delegation here. Just `$(".rowform").find('[type="text"]').on("focus", func...`

Comment: First thank you. But it is not working as I want. Can you do this as first append the error message by clicking a button, then hide on focus.

Answer (score 0):

try following

```
$("#name").focus(function(){
    $(".formerror").remove();
});

$("#btn").on("click",function(){

 $(".formerror").remove();

 if($("#name").val()==""){  
    $("#name_error").append("<div class='formerror'>Please enter your name</div>");
 }
});
```

working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/fzS95/1/

i hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

you can use .`remove()` instead `.hide()`

```
$(".rowform").on("focus", "input", function(){
    $(this).closest(".rowform").find(".formerror").remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you want to implement it, but, I hope this helps:

```
<div class="rowform">
    <label for="name">Name<span class='name-check'>*</span>:</label>
    <input type="text" class="mid" name="name" id="name" onFocus="fcs('name', this);"/><span id="name_error"></span>
</div>

<script>
    function fcs(err,obj) {
        if( $(obj).val() == "" ) {
            $("." + err + "-check").show();
        }
        else {
            $("." + err + "-check").hide();
        }
    }
</script>
```